# Shopify API Order creation billing address validation fails

Tags: java, shopify

New to Shopify API here.  I pass JSON data via POST to Shopify API.  The order is successfully created, but the billing address (pasted below) is not being populated.  When I try other addresses, it succeeds and shows up under "Billing Address" for the order.  Is there any logging or API response messaging we can tap into to get some more info when an address isn't populated?

I have no idea why the address validation is failing.

"billing_address": {
      "address_1": "815 Stewart Drive",
      "city": "Sunnyvale",
      "country": "United States",
      "name": "Planet Granite"
    },

Answer (score 0):

When you POST a request to Shopify, you back a response. If you inspect the response, you will usually, but not always encounter an error message that can help you track down any problems. If you POST an order, and get back an ID, that is a pretty good indication of success. It would be most strange to get an ID, and yet have data you provided not be present. Anyway, check the response from Shopify for messages, that is a good start.

Comment: It took me all day yesterday but upon looking more closely at the end of the night, I realized I had the JSON text written as "address_1" instead of "address1" which is why the address validation was failing.  There must be some sort of log/error messaging that comes back from Shopify that would have indicated this to me early on.  I get 201 created response but no details.  The order was created successfully through the API but address validation failed.  There wasn't even an indication of such at the address validation level....

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it should be address1 `instead` of `address_1`.

> There wasn't even an indication of such at the address validation
>   level

True that. Shopify doesn't send any info. If a particular field is not necessary for creating an order, shopify will just ignore it. Not only in orders API but others as well.

If you still want to check if created order had all details that you passed or not, you can compare the data that you sent with the data you get back from response.